# Nginx React App - Allowing only one location to be accessible

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a server on DigitalOcean that hosts my web app.
The server hosts the API (using Flask) and my web app (React).
I managed to set up the Nginx to serve the app and the API using 2 different domains.
Now I'm facing a problem.
I'm, trying to add another domain that I need to be able to **access only one page** in the react app.
I can't find a way to set up the configuration to allow that.

```
server {
server_name www.domain domain;
root /var/www/path/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location / { deny all; }
location = / { }
location /test {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /favicon.ico {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /static/ {
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot }
```

In my other config files I just use `try_files $uri /index.html;` and it works perfectly.
I need this domain to be able to accept requests for one path only (domain.com/confirm/token)

Comment: Just use an exact location match: `location = /confirm/token { ... }` and then 404 route `location / { ... }`.

Comment: The thing is that the / path is required. when the page on /confirm/token loads it loads from /static/*. And the 'token' I've mentioned is a real token that is changing, so the location = /confirm/token or location = /confirm/ doesn't work for me. I'm now trying to find a way to just block the /login directory but this doesn't work for me as well. I think it's the router that give me trouble.